# Difference between Wortschatz and Lexikon?

Tags: vocabulary

What's the main difference between *Wortschatz* and *Lexikon*?

Comment: They are entirely different words. Wortschatz = "word treasure", i.e. a set of words someone learned. Lexikon is... a lexicon.

Comment: @peterh Lexikon  bedeutet auch Wortschatz. Siehe die Begriffserklärung bei Wikipedia (link in meiner Antwort).

Comment: While *Wortschatz* is only about a person's knowledge of words, *Lexicon* can mean **also** a book listing words.

Answer (score 6):

You are of course not referring to *Lexikon* as in *encyclopedia*, but as in the English word *lexicon* that also [exists in German](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon_(Begriffskl%C3%A4rung)).

*Wortschatz* and *Lexikon* seem to be identical in meaning in that respect.
However, you can see from the comment to your question and from the other answer that in German (outside linguistic circles), *Lexikon* is mostly used as *encyclopedia*.

Comment: Interessant, diese Bedeutung kannte ich tatsächlich nicht. - Damit ist dann aber auch klar, dass diese Frage *nicht* off topic ist.

Comment: Yes, that was the reference of my question.

Answer (score 3):

Wortschatz are all the words you know. Lexikon is a book that explains words, usually in the same language.
A Wörterbuch often offers a translation from Language 1 <> Language 2 but also same language Wörterbücher exist.

edit:
As mentioned in other answers and comments (I myself was unaware of this), Lexikon may also be a synonym to Wortschatz, however, the average German will picture the Lexikon as the encyclopedia.

Comment: And Wortschatz can - especially when talking about someone's knowledge of a foreign language - be sub-divided into *aktiver* and *passiver* Wortschatz. Passiver Wortschatz is the totality of all words you know and understand when you hear or read them, while aktiver Wortschatz contains the words you know well enough to use them when speaking or writing.

Comment: You should note, however, that *Lexikon* can well be used as a synomym of *Wortschatz*, i.e. for the entirety of words somebody knows, not for a book or other object. At least in higher registers of speech.

Comment: *Der Duden* does not list a meaning equivalent to *Wortschatz* in its [definition of Lexikon](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lexikon). It might be a neologism taken from English. There is [Lexik](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Lexik), however.

Comment: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon mentions it.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not an expert in that field, but as a native speaker I would suggest the following. A lexicon (often similar to an encyclopedia) is a *tangible asset*. Usually a book that you can hold in your hand. You use it as a source of help if you want an explanation to a word. ‘Wortschatz’ is more an *intangible asset*. It refers to your or to someone else’s knowledge. You can train it by learning a language and memorizing more words. Similarly to computer science, programming or chat bots, they are only as intelligent as the (limited) ‘Wortschatz’ they’ve been trained with.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: This is correct so far, and still a bit misleading, because you left out the crucial information that *Lexikon* can also be used as a full synonym of *Wortschatz*, at least in scientific communication. *Paul verfügt über ein umfangreiches Lexikon* does rather not refer to a book but to his ability to use words.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann as I said: I’m not an expert. But honestly, as a native speaker I would even say that those two words DONT have the same meaning and I would never ever use them this way. No matter what official sources indicate.

Answer (score 0):

### Lexikon

English: *encyclopedia, lexicon*

A book or a website with descriptions of many terms. Each section starts with a headword that will be explained and after it comes the explanation of this term. If the Lexicon is printed (i.e. a book) then the sections are sorted alphabetically by the headwords.

This posting here is a sort of a Mini-Lexikon

[Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexikon) is a *Lexikon.*

---

### Wortschatz

English: *vocabulary, lexicon, word pool*

1. A set of words that is known by a single person (Wortschatz einer Person; a person's vocabulary).

   The set of all words that this person can understand (by reading and listening) is called *"passiver Wortschatz"* (passive vocabulary). The set of all words that this person really uses for writing and speaking is called *"aktiver Wortschatz"* (active vocabulary).
2. The set of all words that belong to a language (Wortschatz einer Sprache; a language's vocabulary.

   The [Wörterverzeichnis des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Woerterverzeichnis_2016_veroeffentlicht_2017.pdf) is the aim to list the German *Wortschatz.* But a *Wortschatz* is just an unordered set.

---

### Wörterbuch

engl: *dictionary, lexicon, wordbook*

1. A list of word-to-word translations from one language to another, sometimes also with short explanations, but much shorter than in a *Lexikon* (encyclopedia).

   [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/englisch-deutsch/W%C3%B6rterbuch) is such a *Wörterbuch*
2. A list of all (or the most important) words of a language together with short explanation about the usage in the context of the language.

   [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/W%C3%B6rterbuch) is such a *Wörterbuch*

Comment: Du scheinst Philips Hinweis übersehen zu haben, dass *unter Linguistikern* auch im Deutschen das Wort "Lexikon" mit der Bedeutung "Wortschatz" verwendet wird.